# How to launch url in a modal?

Tags: angularjs, iframe, modal-dialog

I am trying to launch a modal that has a url in it when user clicks a button.

I have something like these:

```
myModal.html:

<div class="modal-header">
    Title 1
</div>
<div class="modal-body">
  <iframe id="iframe" ng-src="{{my_url}}">
</div>

In JS:

$scope.clickButton = function(){
    var modal = $uibModal.open({
        templateUrl: 'myModal.html'
        controller: 'myCtrl',         
    });
})

In myCtrl:

  ....
  $scope.my_url = 'http://myotherproject/project/index.html';
  ....
```

I want the url launched as soon as the modal shows. Iframe approach works but I was wondering if there are more elegant way to do this. Thanks for the help!

Comment: Only other way is if you control the css and scripts and can load html with ajax.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on what are you trying to achieve here, if you just want to display some html with your own styles, then you can use $sce.trustAsHtml and ng-bind-html directive. But if you want some custom styles inside and some js, then iframe is probably safer solution.

```js
angular.module('app', []);

angular
  .module('app')
  .controller('Example', function ($sce) {
    const someHTML = `
      <strong>blah</strong><br>
      <hr>
      <h1>Blah</h1>
    `;
  
    this.someHTML = $sce.trustAsHtml(someHTML);
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.5/angular.js"></script>
<div ng-app="app" ng-controller="Example as Example">
  <div ng-bind-html="Example.someHTML"></div>
</div>
```

You can also inject some html and compile it. If you want your html to behave like regular angular template.

```js
angular.module('app', []);

angular.module('app').directive('compile', ($compile) => {
  return {
    restrict: 'A',
    link: (scope, element, attrs) => {
      attrs.$observe('compile', (html) => {
        const content = $compile(html)(scope);
        
        element.empty();
        element.append(content);
      });
    }
  };
});

angular.module('app').controller('Example', function () {
  this.x = 0;
  this.someHTML = `
    <div>
      {{Example.x}}<br>
      <button type="button" ng-click="Example.x = Example.x + 1">+1</button>
    </div>
  `;
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.5/angular.js"></script>
<div ng-app="app" ng-controller="Example as Example">
  <div compile="{{Example.someHTML}}"></div>
</div>
```

In all example I skipped fetching part, as I assume you know how to use $http.